# is there a way to watch inputs (v-model) in a v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an Array of objects that I loop through, and I wana watch an input related to each object, but the problem is the v-model="something" : this something changes  so I dont know what to watch

```
<table class="table displaynone" id="table-sauces" >
    <tr v-for="o in order">                          
        <td>@{{o.produit}} @{{o.num}}</td>
            <td v-for="sauce in les_sauce">                  
                <input type="radio" :name="o.produit+o.num" @click="$emit(setsauce(o.is_menu))" :value="sauce.id" v-model="o.sauce">  
                  @{{sauce.name}}
                <img :src="sauce.link">
        </td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

How can I watch the value of that input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having two levels of loop, and they seem to loop on different things (`order` and `les_sauce`).

Nevertheless, here is a simplified example that uses the inner loop of your code (`v-for="sauce in les_sauce"`) and shows how you can watch for changes:

You can create a separate child component for each of those array items and watch for changes inside the child component.

For example, this is the looping part in parent component template:

```html
<td v-for="sauce in les_sauce">
    <sauce-view :sauce="sauce" :ord="o"></sauce-view>
</td>
```

and your child component:

```js
Vue.component('sauce-view', {
    props: ["sauce", "ord"],
    template: `
        <div class="sauce-view">
            <input type="radio" :name="ord.produit+ord.num"
            @click="$emit(setsauce(ord.is_menu))"
            :value="sauce.id" v-model="ord.sauce">  @{{sauce.name}}
            <img :src="sauce.link">
        </div>`,
    watch: {
        sauce: function() {
            // this will get triggered within sauce-view component, when one of your "sauce" changes
        },
        ord: function() {
            // this will get triggered within sauce-view component, when one of your "o" changes
        }
    }
})
```

As shown in the sample code for child component code above, here you can watch for individual array items from parent - `o` and `sauce`

Note: `o` in parent gets passed as `ord` to the child component. This is an example to show how the variables need not be the same in parent and child components.

**EDIT: additional information after comment #4 (deep watching)**

In my sample code above, I did not set `deep:true` which is needed for watching deep.

Here are the relevant lines from the [API document](http://vuejs.org/api/#vm-watch):

> **Option: deep**
>
> To also detect nested value changes inside Objects, you need to pass in deep: true in the options argument.

In your case, you can modify the sample code above as follows:

```
watch: {
    sauce: {
        handler: function() {
            // this will get triggered when any of the nested values of "sauce" change
        },
        deep: true  // this enables watching the nested values inside this object 
    },
    ord: function() {
        // this will get triggered within sauce-view component, when one of your "o" changes
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: whene I copy the 
<td v-for="sauce in les_sauce">
    <sauce-view :sauce="sauce"></sauce-view>
</td>
in my code; will it just be cpoied and pats in the HTML and thene run the loop order? cuz it didnt recognize the 'o' which came from v-for="o in order"
Property or method "o" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in component <sauce-view>)

Comment: Updated my answer. You need to pass more values to the child component based on what you need.

Comment: it worked!!, Bigg thanks man, you helped me understand lot of thing foing on the on component

Comment: the watch is not triggered when I change the sauce value !!

Comment: i just noticed that your sauce is an object. You need to use the `deep: true` option as given in the [API docs](http://vuejs.org/api/#vm-watch). I will update my answer shortly.